# java: comparing value of 2D-array with value of arraylist at the same column

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D-Array with a lot of zeros and some other values. In the first step I am adding up all rows in one column to find out the sum of each column. The result of the sum is saved in an arraylist.
Now I need to compare each value in the 2D-Array if it is equal to the sum of its column in the arraylist. If it is equal the first value of the row will be saved in a seperate arraylist.

As an example:

```
          {A, 0, 0, 6, 0}
          {B, 0, 2, 0, 2}
          {C, 0, 1, 0, 0}
          {D, 3, 0, 0, 2}

Arraylist    {3, 3, 6, 4}
```

I want to compare each value with the value in the arraylist at the same position.

My code so far:

```
List sumList = new ArrayList();
for(int c = 1; c < excelMatrix.length; c++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length-1; r++){
        sum = excelMatrix[r][c] + sum;
        sumList.add(sum);
    }
}

List checkList = new ArrayList();
for(int c = 1; c < excelMatrix.length; c++){
    for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length-1; r++){
        if(excelMatrix[r][c].equals(sumList)){
            checkList.add(excelMatrix[r][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until the comparision of the array value with the value of the arraylist.

Comment: for the checking condition make it ->  for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length-1; r++)

Comment: @GovindMadhu sorry I missed that while posting the question. In my code I have the -1 already.

Comment: Are you sure, the sum is getting calculated properly? From what I'm seeing from the code, it's not  the case. In the first for loop, c=0 should be there instead of c=1, so that you can take the values for matrix[0][0],[1,0][2,0][3,0]. By your current code, it'll take matrix[0,1][1,1][2,1][3,1].

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an integer with the list, not with the correspondent sum of column value in list.

If `excelMatrix` is `Integer` array, do this way:

```
if(excelMatrix[r][c].equals(sumList.get(c-1)))
```

Otherwise,

```
if(excelMatrix[r][c] == sumList.get(c-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify types in the example code so I assumed it like:

```
    String[][] excelMatrix = {{"A", "0", "0", "6", "0"},
                              {"B", "0", "2", "0", "2"},
                              {"C", "0", "1", "0", "0"},
                              {"D", "3", "0", "0", "2"}};

    List<String> sumList = new ArrayList<>();
    sumList.add("3");
    sumList.add("3");
    sumList.add("6");
    sumList.add("4");
```

And modified your `for` loop like this:

```
    List<String> checkList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int c = 0; c < excelMatrix.length; c++){
        for(int r = 1; r < excelMatrix[0].length; r++){
            if(excelMatrix[c][r].equals(sumList.get(r-1))){
                 checkList.add(excelMatrix[c][0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

At the end

```
    for(int i = 0; i<checkList.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(checkList.get(i));
    }
```

gives

> AD

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unrelated to the answer you are looking for. The code you are using to calculate the sum of the column elements is wrong. Use the below code to get the proper list of sums.

```
   List sumList = new ArrayList();
        for(int c = 0; c < excelMatrix.length; c++){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < excelMatrix.length; r++){
                sum = excelMatrix[r][c] + sum;
                System.out.println(sum);

            }
            sumList.add(sum);
        }
```